WiFi Connected but No Internet on ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
I’m new to Linux. My WiFi worked fine on the first day, but today it shows "connected" without providing internet access. To get the internet working, I have to toggle the WiFi off and on. I’ve tried various solutions from YouTube and Google, but nothing seems to work. Any advice on what might be causing this or how to fix it?

Finally found the solution,if anyone encounter this problem just off the fast boot option from windows setting and then you will good to go.
